# Computer always has a black screen

Tags: windows-vista, black-screen-of-death

My computed apparently overheated Thursday night and has yet to begin working again.

At first, I was able to start it up as usual until it prompted me for system repair, which I did. It managed to overheat and freeze up during this process. I waited a few hours and tried to start it up again, but only got a black screen. I turned it off by holding the power button and tried again, yet once again to no avail. I decided to let it sit off overnight hoping that'd solve the problem as it typically does.

After trying again this morning, it still only awakens to a black screen. I have continued to try: the only progress I made was once turning it on to receive the screen for shutting down improperly, and instead chose to start windows normally. It simply stayed black from there as if no progress were made at all.

**Does anyone know what could be the cause of this or how to fix it?** I'd like to know a way other than asking Best Buy; the last time my computer was left in their hands they cleared all of my information (despite being specifically instructed not to do so) and cost me years of work.

Comment: The answer may be directly related to a particular brand and specific model, please post these details by using the edit feature.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you checked your fan's and heat syncs? Do all the fans spin up? details.... Also if you have years of work on a single computer with no backups your asking for trouble. As much as I am not a fan of them, you can't blame best buy for you past problems.

Comment: What do you mean by black screen?  Are you getting a BIOS show but you never get the 'loading windows' screens?  You have said all you get is a black screen, but then you also say you have gotten the "windows was shutdown improperly" window.  If you're not getting the BIOS show, then you almost certainly have a hardware problem with the video adapter, RAM, CPU, system board, or power supply.  Do you hear the "POST OK" single beep but just do not see anything beyond that?  It's essential that you're very precise about what you see your computer doing to know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the system turning it unexpectedly it may have corrupted your Windows installation.

Confirm the following:

- Try running the system with the side door off
- Before turning the system on, unplug the power and double check that all heat sinks etc are seated correctly. The CPU Heatsink may be loose.
- The GPU is correctly seated in the PCIE slot

Also try running in safe mode to see if you can boot into windows.